# mPDF Генерация документа с точными размерами

Tags: php, mpdf

Конечная задача: 
Есть SVG все координаты в нем в миллиметрах. Необходимо дать возможность его напечатать максимально просто с точными размерами.

Пробовал печатать на прямую. Размеры "плавают".

Решил попробовать через PDF. Взял библиотеку mPDF. Вставил svg туда - размеры нарушены: 100мм х 100мм дают 94мм х 94мм на печати.

Просто добавил на страницу блок (div). Задал размер 100mm на 100mm. На печати получилось 97мм x 92mm

Может кто сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Comment: Вопрос стоит снять. Оказалось была включена галка масштаб. Видимо случайно задел.

Comment: Вопрос снят. Была галка масштаб активирована.